# What game is on the laptop in the background of this cat photo?

Tags: game-identification

I came across this cute cat while browsing some posts:

[image: picture of a cat; there's a laptop in the background with what appears to be a video game on its screen]

Does anyone know the name of the game on the laptop in the background?

Comment: Cat. +1. (And, you know, it's on-topic).

Comment: I actually recognised World of Warcraft GUI despite not having played it for dozen of years. The open window reminded me of the Quest tab, whist the circles inside it reminded me of glyphs (although it seems to be neither according to the accepted answer).

Comment: I'm honestly surprised 20 people didn't answer all at the same time

Comment: @rtaft I blame it on the timezone⸮

Comment: I was completely unaware that there was a laptop in this photo until it was pointed out in the question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### *World of Warcraft* (WoW)

I ran the image through various reverse image search engines. [KarmaDecay](http://karmadecay.com/) led me to this [2019 Reddit /r/aww post](https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/comments/bnyaha/smol_kitten_is_worried/) (the image has been deleted in the post), where several commenters say that the game is *WoW*.

Yandex image search led me to this [Pinterest page that had the same image as your post](https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/510384570254972484/), which in turn linked to its source, this [Imgur post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttCZY.jpg) by [TheMarebear](https://imgur.com/user/TheMarebear) from 2015 (likely the original). The caption by the OP of the Imgur post says that the game is *WoW*.

> Good thinking, I didn't want to play World of Warcraft anyways.

###### Additional info from comments:

@[Joachim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/222022/joachim):

> "Hogger", mentioned in the Reddit thread, is also a character from *WoW*. The image on Pinterest is of [a much higher quality](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/29/fa/35/29fa35f1eb6b0f67d140a3833ab61cad.jpg), and we can easily read things like the location: [The Maclure Vineyards](https://wowwiki-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Maclure_Vineyards).

@[isanae](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/127873/isanae):

> Based on the image date (22 November 2015) and the HealBot 6.2 addon folder visible in Finder in the background, below the game (6.2.2.1 came out 3 November 2015), it would likely be version 6.2.3 of the Warlords of Draenor expansion, released on 17 November 2015.

@[Mast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/93118/mast):

> Specifically you're looking at what talent trees looked like at the time. This one is of a Retribution (DPS) Paladin.

The following is a higher-resolution and clearer version of the image from the Imgur post; click/tap the image to see it in full size:

[image: image described above]

Comment: do you know which version of wow is this?

Comment: @BlackCrystal Based on the image date (22 November 2015) and the HealBot 6.2 addon folder visible in Finder in the background, below the game (6.2.2.1 came out 3 November 2015), it would likely be version 6.2.3 of the Warlords of Draenor expansion, released on 17 November 2015.

Comment: Specifically you're looking at what talent trees looked like at the time. This one is of a Retribution (DPS) Paladin.

Comment: @Mast, `@isanae, thanks for the information. I’ve added those to the answer.